# Jenkins - Restrict Jobs to Certain Nodes

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to find out how to set Jenkins jobs to run only on certain slave nodes.

There is mention of this in the documentation under the labels header:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

However, when I've looked into this issue I've seen people point to going to the job configuration and in the "general" tab selecting "restrict which nodes this job can run on" check box.

However, on my jenkins setup I have no option for this checkbox, and I cannot figure out how to enable it. I've looked in all the tabs available for the job and found no reference to restricting them or mention of labels.

The only plugins we have to my knowledge is one to use PTC Integrity as a version control method. I've posted a screenshot of my job configuration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKGk9.png)

Does anyone know what setup step I've messed/what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add Labels to your nodes/slaves; say you add a label 'linux-node' on your slave and then in your pipeline job use them as per use case.

Scripted:-

```
node ('linux-node') {

}
```

Declarative:-

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'linux-node'
    }
}
```